# How to generate documentation from python code looking like "python shell output"

Tags: python, documentation

I want to run some python code i.e. example.py.
I don't want to enter code manually into Python shell since it slow:

```
x = 1
x
y = 2
y + x
y
```

And I'd like to achieve such output:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x
1
>>> y = 2
>>> y + x
3
>>> y
2
```

It looks that is simple to answer, but very hard to find how to do it.

*Since there was some questions this is not **pattern** to document **"large code"** that is for documenting/testing **code snippets/examples**!*

Comment: Why not write your code as actual Python rather than relying on the shell's interaction?

Comment: Why not use print? or try ironpython. Also you could write it in the shell and then convert the shell text into a python file.

Comment: Why not use copy and paste?  How much of this do you have to do?  Are you writing a tutorial in Python?  If so, you only have to do it once and you're done.  Please explain the use case for this.

Comment: @Lattyware since such format is good present simple examples.

Comment: @robertking Not want print since to slow to prepare examples.

Comment: @S.Lott Copy and paste is good for once as you said - not good for many updates or large code.

Comment: I think the key is "simple examples". Generating large amounts of code to display as an interactive python session seems like a bad way to document something, IMO.

Comment: @Wooble Sure it not way to document large application - purpose of it is simple examples and code snippets.

Comment: "not good for many updates or large code"?  How much of this do you have to do?    Are you writing a tutorial in Python? Please explain the use case for this

Comment: @S.Lott Purpose could as you imagine i.e. tutorial or code snippets preparations.

Comment: How can it be difficult to copy and paste "tutorial or code snippets"?  I'm utterly baffled.  Please explain how it is so difficult to copy and paste that this kind of complexity is needed.

Comment: @S.Lott It is not need explain economy in this case at all :) Copy&paste is much slower 2-10 times and not fault tolerant - you develop code with iteration - so each iteration take 2-10 time more with C&P - it waste of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the [`InteractiveConsole`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/code.html#interactive-console-objects) in the [`code`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/code.html) module, and it **support multilines**:

```
import code

console = code.InteractiveConsole()

more_input = False
with open('example.py') as source:
    for line in source:
        if not more_input:
            print('>>> ' + line.rstrip())
        else:
            print('... ' + line.rstrip())

        more_input = console.push(line)
```

If you wonder how the `more_input` flag works, take a look at the [doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole.push):

> `InteractiveConsole.push(line):`
>
> > [...] The return value is *True* if more input is required, *False* if the line was dealt with in some way (this is the same as `runsource()`).

I've test it on an `example.py` that looks like:

```
x = 1
x
y = 2
y + x

a = (
    1,
    2,
    3
    )
print(a)
```

and the result was:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x
1
>>> y = 2
>>> y + x
3
>>> 
>>> a = (
...     1,
...     2,
...     3
...     )
>>> print(a)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: @Chameleon: Whould this mean that you're going to accept it? :)

Comment: Sure since it the best! - You could improve little code style - order flow as data comes (simplify readability) - rename flag to meaning (readability) ... :) I give some hours to give chance others.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
f = open('example.py', 'r')

for line in f:
  print('>>> ' + line)
  try:
    print(eval(line))
  except SyntaxError:
    exec(line)
```

Comment: be careful of multiline strings but this will work for his code.

Comment: You really need to do this:  `global _; _= eval(line); if _ is not None: print( _ )` to get slightly closer to REPL behavior.

Comment: @robertking sure it not support multiline but it look that is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's in the current directory:

```
execfile('example.py')
```

See [execfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=execfile#execfile) docs.

Comment: This does not emit the `>>> ...` lines.

Answer (score -1):

I would not know a way to do so. But you don't have to enter it manually - just do copy & paste...

Comment: Not works if code is multiline and slow if you doing many code updates - need to repeat C&P.